Can a Camel Bean be supplied or injected with additional data?
According to Camel's doc the Bean component has a parameters query parameter. If I understand Parameter binding correctly this works with bean handler methods only, right?
Now, with a class:
class MyBean implements Consumer<Object> {

    String id;

    MyBean( final String id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    MyBean setId( final String id ) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    @Handler
    public void accept(Object o) {
        // ...
    }

is it possible to do something like:

setting attributes with an associative array or a Map:

String[] attributes = { "id", "My bean's id.", "attr2", "value2", ... };
.bean( MyBean.class, attributes )
.bean( MyBean.class, Map.of( "id", "My bean's id.", "attr2", "value2", ... ) )


or via (positional) constructor parameters:

.bean( MyBean.class, { "MyBean()", "My bean's id." } )


or by invoking methods:

.bean( MyBean.class, { "setId(\"My bean's id.\")" } )


or with URIs:

.to( "bean:MyBean?id=\"My bean's id.\"&ctorArgs=\"My bean's id.\"&method=setId(\"My bean's id.\")" )

